# TFS unit test passes on build machine but fails on TFS-Build

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfsbuild

I have a unit test that fails when it is run by TFS-build, while it passes when I run it on the build machine (through Visual Studio)
[It passes on my local machine too]

Does anyone have any information or tips for this issue?

The test does use data from a file.
Another test (which doesn't use PDFTron) passes! (I mean the issue isn't in the files form the data source)
This is the code:

```cs
// The first part of the test method is converting a Doc file to a Pdf
// I do it by PDFTron (PDFNet.dll)

public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }

[TestMethod]
[DataSource(@"System.Data.Odbc", @"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=C:\FilesRepo.xls;DefaultDir=.", "Doc$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
public void ConvertDocToPdf()
{
    string path = TestContext.FilePath;
    string pdfPath = path + ".pdf";

    using (PDFDoc pdfdoc = new PDFDoc())
    {
        pdftron.PDF.Convert.ToPdf(pdfdoc, path); // <-- Here I get the exception:
        // Exception: 
        //  Message: Unable to open the file
        //  Conditional expression: m_stream != NULL
        //  Filename   : StdFile.cpp
        //  Function   : trn::Filters::StdFile::InitW
        //  Linenumber : 210
        pdfdoc.Save(pdfPath, SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized);
    }
    // More code
}
```

Comment: Does the test use data from a file? There are some differences how Visual Studio handles files that are used in tests in contrast to how TFS Build handles those files.

Comment: It would help if you posted the failing test + its entiry fixture (base class, helper methods, ...)

Comment: @Markus the test does use data from a file.
Another test (which doesn't use PDFTron) passes! (I mean the issue isn't in the files form the data source)

Comment: The exception:
    Exception: 
        Message: Unable to open the file
        Conditional expression: m_stream != NULL
        Filename   : StdFile.cpp
        Function   : trn::Filters::StdFile::InitW
        Linenumber : 210

Comment: The data source references a file "C:\FilesRepo.xls". Is this file present on the build server? It would be better not to use absolute paths but to deploy all files that are used in tests (see the DeploymentItemAttribute class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute.aspx)